# Need to get value pointing to a symlink

Tags: perl

I have a symlink in a path that points to a directory like below:

```
cd /home/test/test1/test2

ls -lrt

symlink -> 200101-011
```

I want to store the directory value `200101-011` into a variable, say `$dir`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[readlink](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readlink.html) "Returns the value of a symbolic link":

```
my $dir = readlink '/home/test/test1/test2/symlink';
```